# Помогите с getItemCount()

Tags: java, android

вызываю так:

```
rv_news = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.userWall);
                refresh_layout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.refresh_layout);
                mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
                mAdapter = new NewsAdapter(items);
                mAdapter.setItemClickListener(getApplicationContext());
                rv_news.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                rv_news.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

---

```
public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Item> mItems;
    private SimpleDateFormat mSimpleDateFormat;
    private OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }
    public NewsAdapter(List<Item> items) {
        mItems = items;
        mSimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.news_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Item item = mItems.get(position);
        holder.tv_author.setText(item.getAuthor().getName());
        holder.tv_likes_count.setText(Integer.toString(item.getLikes()));
        holder.tv_reposts_count.setText(Integer.toString(item.getReposts()));
        holder.tv_date.setText(mSimpleDateFormat.format(new Date(item.getDate() * 1000)));
        new DownloadImageTask(holder.iv_avatar).execute(item.getAuthor().getAvatar());
        if (item instanceof Photo) {
            Photo photo = (Photo) item;
            holder.tv_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (photo.getSmallPhotos() != null) {
                new DownloadImageTask(holder.iv_sample).execute(photo.getSmallPhotos().get(0));
            }
        } else {
            Post post = (Post) item;
            holder.tv_text.setText(post.getText());
            if (post.getAttachments() != null) {
                List<Attachment> attachments = post.getAttachments();
                boolean isPhoto = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < attachments.size() && !isPhoto; i++) {
                    if (attachments.get(i) instanceof PhotoAttachment) {
                        isPhoto = true;
                        PhotoAttachment photo = (PhotoAttachment) attachments.get(i);
                        new DownloadImageTask(holder.iv_sample).execute(photo.getSmallPhoto());
                    }
                }
                if (!isPhoto) holder.iv_sample.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
    public void setItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        mItemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private CircleImageView iv_avatar;
        private TextView tv_author;
        private TextView tv_date;
        private TextView tv_text;
        private ImageView iv_sample;
        private TextView tv_likes_count;
        private TextView tv_reposts_count;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            iv_avatar = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_avatar);
            tv_author = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_author);
            tv_date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
            tv_text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_text);
            iv_sample = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_sample);
            tv_likes_count = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_likes_count);
            tv_reposts_count = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_reposts_count);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mItemClickListener != null) {
                mItemClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

постоянно выбивает ошибку: на вот этом месте `public int getItemCount() { return mItems.size(); }`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 

'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
at rasschet.oma.sviter.by.adapter.NewsAdapter$override.getItemCount(NewsAdapter.java:35)
at rasschet.oma.sviter.by.adapter.NewsAdapter$override.access$dispatch(NewsAdapter.java)
at rasschet.oma.sviter.by.adapter.NewsAdapter.getItemCount(NewsAdapter.java:0)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:3170)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3067)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3518)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)

может кто знает как исправить ее?
```

Comment: а у Вас сам List<Item> items подготовлен?

Comment: В конструктор адаптера передаете ```null```, поэтому и ```NPE```

Comment: Имел ввиду что объект ```mItems``` у вас не инициализирован, потому в конструктор адаптера идет ```null```